# ANTRL plsql grammar does not detect missing ;

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm using this grammar file to parse a sql file before it goes to the database:
https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/sql/plsql/PlSqlLexer.g4

Currently it finds errors in the sql syntax but does not detect missing ; at the end of instructions:

```
Select * From  d where d.DISCOUNTNAME = '2023'
BEGIN
Insert into DISCOUNT_MAIN_PARAM Values ('9922');
IF SQL%ROWCOUNT = 1 THEN
  COMMIT;
ELSE
  ROLLBACK;
END IF;
END;
/
Select * From d where d.DISCOUNTNAME = '2023';
```

This would obviously fail because of the missing ; at the first line, how can I work around that ?

Comment: What you posted isn't PL/SQL.  It looks like a `SQL*Plus` script that is supposed to be three separate commands (2 SQL statements 1 PL/SQL block).  I doubt this parser is designed to parse `SQL*Plus` scripts.

Comment: Why SQL PLUS? I agree that it's 3 separate statements but for the exemple using a script with the content:

SELECT 1 FROM; => ERROR

SELECT 1 FROM DUAL => OK

Comment: The `/` after the PL/SQL block indicates that this is a `SQL*Plus` script (though lots of other client-side tools can handle at least most `SQL*Plus` scripts).  I guess my question is whether the intention of this grammar is to parse SQL, PL/SQL, `SQL*Plus` scripts, or something out.  They're all different though similar languages.

Comment: Reading your answer I realise that it's probably fine for plsql blocks but not for sql statements. I looked a lot and didn't find anything better than that except commercial parsers

Comment: Taking a step back, why are you parsing a file before sending it to the database?  If you have a valid file with multiple statements, you can't just send that block to the database via most (all?) client-side APIs (JDBC, ODP.Net, etc.).  Depending on what problem you're solving, you may have other options.

Comment: It might handle a single SQL statement OK, looking at the definitions in the lexer. And a semicolon is a statement separator, not a terminator, so it often isn't required or valid (e.g. in a JDBC query, or `execute immediate`). The issue is probably trying to include multiple SQL and/or PL/SQL statements/blocks at once - i.e. a script. You can't do that in JDBC etc. either.

Comment: @JustinCave Yes I want to validate the syntax before it goes to the database to avoid execution error because of an invalid syntax

Comment: @AlexPoole when the sql atetement is inside a plsql block a missing ; will result in an error but outside the plsql block it doesn't

Comment: But why are you using a parser to look for errors?  There are a vast array of syntax errors in parsable PL/SQL that might be thrown at runtime (referencing packages that don't exist, permissions errors, etc.) so you'd still have to handle the majority of likely syntax errors.  And any parser is going to have trouble occasionally with valid syntax (Oracle maintained separate SQL parsers for the SQL and PL/SQL engines for a while and couldn't keep them in sync as new features were added).

Comment: You mention Flyway in a comment on a different answer.  If you're building checks in a release pipeline, it would seem odd to use a PL/SQL parser on checked in code just like it would be weird to run a Java parser over checked in Java code.  Your Java developers presumably verify that their code compiles before they check it in (or it breaks the build when they check in parsable code that references non-existent classes).  Your PL/SQL developers should do the same.

Comment: Yeah, this seems like a very strange thing to be doing.  Sounds like an XY problem.

Comment: @JustinCave Maybe it's not a good idea and I may have asked the question with the context. We have specific pipeline with flyway to run dml statements in production. These statement are in repositories manages by anaylyst and devlopper where they can deposit scripts to be run by flyway. Believe it or not almost 10% of sql statements fail because of basic syntax problem. Once it goes to the database and flyway fails the change is closed with failed status, I would like to catch thoses errors before execution.

Comment: @CyrilleMODIANO - I'd look at what is leading devs and analysts to have that rate of non-parsable SQL and/or PL/SQL in their scripts.  Do they have an environment where they can test their scripts before they're checked in to the repo?  Does there need to be a code review gate?

Comment: @JustinCave test the script entierly no because it's environnement specific and they don't have access to that environment but check code for syntax error can be done event with no access to the database, I can't force them to have code review in place unfortunately

Comment: @CyrilleMODIANO - Oracle DB itself does not have this problem because it's parser has to parse single statement only. Delimiters are problems of the caller. ANTLR tries to support it but mixing various grammars in single input is problematic.
Also ANTLR can not catch semantic problems. IMHO it would be better idea to let every developer to have own Oracle database running on Docker/WLS. Or use Oracle PDB for each developer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I maintained this grammar at the era of ANTLR3, now it advanced a lot.
What error you get from ANTLR4 parser?

- SQL grammar does not contain `;` - it is just delimiter used by sqlplus tool.
- PL/SQL grammar does contain `;`, therefore sqlplus has to use `/` as statement delimiter. (alone on line)

ANTLR* parser should consume as much as possible from input text. There is also possible error recovery where it can skip tokens or create missing tokens.

Your 'missing' semicolon is not actually missing in context of SQL grammar.
Semicolons are not allowed in SQL and Oracle's SQL does not have any special "end-of-query" keyword.

In case of sqlplus tool grammar, there are one-liners introduced by special sqlplus `keyword` and SQL/PLSQL statements - these have to be delimited either by `;` or `/`

Comment: interesting, thanks for your input, so you're saying that other client don't need the ; at the end of sql statements? this means I could send my code exemple through other clients and they'll execute it without problems ?

Comment: It's up to them. Most of them(like SQLDeveloper) try to mimic sqlplus logic. Mine tool (Tora) has some fuzzy parser and is able to detect that (in most cases). Neither OCI nor JDBC won't allow you to send more that one statement. So each tool has to remove trailing `;` from SQL and trailing `/`  before sending single statement to database.
Actually having trailing `;` as part of SQL statement is one of the most common programmers errors in JDBC. Oracle database wont parse such a statement.

Comment: I'm going to do some more test, oud database deployment tool is flyway, I will see if not specifing ; at the end of sql report an error, never tried.

Comment: @CyrilleMODIANO the SQL language, at least in Oracle, has no semicolon in its syntax. The PL/SQL language does. Your sample code is a mixture of the two languages,  which as I understand it ANTLR (not ANTRL btw) does not claim to parse.

Comment: @CyrilleMODIANO also just to add, in SQL\*Plus `;` is simply the default setting for sqlterminator. If you `set sqlterminator !` then `!` will do the same job. You can also `set sqlterminator off` and rely instead on `/` and `run` commands.